# Change all the video thumbnails at once

Tags: windows-10, video, thumbnails, user-folders

Is there a way to change all the video thumbnails to a default thumbnail in a particular folder in windows 10?

Present Thumbnail:

[image]

Expected Thumbnail:

[image]

Comment: I don't think so as the thumbnails are generated automatically from the videos.

Answer (score 0):

okay so I found this [it seems as if it does what you want](https://www.videohelp.com/software/Video-Thumbnails-Maker)

or you could use some sort of this command

```
tageditor -s cover=my-cover.jpg --max-padding 125000 -f My_video.mp4
```

but you would need to figure out how to edit the cmd to work on a folder of videos